# What kind of mouthfeel is the 'soft and tender'?

Tags: meaning

I read this sentence from [this article](https://foodfornet.com/most-tender-steak-cuts/):

> Some cuts have *soft and tender* muscles that melt in your mouth, while other cuts are known
> for their toughness and leanness.

An excerpt from [the other article](https://prime-13.com/what-does-tough-and-chewy-steak-mean/):

> At most times, many people visiting a steakhouse expect *tender and soft* steak, as it is said to have incredible flavor.

From googling, I know that the 'tenderness' indicates the easiness for chewing while softness is something not hard. But I don't see any difference between 'soft' and 'tender' when we talk about tasting food. If it is soft, the meat would be tender.

What mouthfeel do we mean when we say the meat is 'soft and tender'? Is it just to emphasize the tenderness? If it is to emphasize the tenderness, why not just say, 'it's very(ultra, really,..) tender'?

Comment: Consider a rare steak which seems easily malleable on the plate as opposed to being cooked to the point where it stiffens. Such a steak will feel *soft*, but can still not be *tender* once you bite into it and have a hard time separating it with your teeth.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski I can get the feeling of it. The well-done would be too hard to be soft but it can be tender. And a medium steak could be tender and soft at the same time?

Comment: Using "taste" here is odd. Neither soft nor tender is a "taste." Using "quality" to describe this would be more natural.

Comment: @JasonBassford Or if you're trying to sound like a cooking show, you'd use [mouthfeel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouthfeel).

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thanks. I updated it to the mouthfeel.

Comment: @kevin012 - Note that "mouthfeel" is a jargon term that, until recently, you'd only hear from professional chefs or wine tasters. That's why I made the joke about "trying to sound like a cooking show." A more ordinary term would be "texture."